# onclick change css on one html element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

inside view I have

```
<a ng-class="{'active' : check}" ng-click="doSomething()">1</a>
<a ng-class="{'active' : check}" ng-click="doSomething()">2</a>

 $scope.doSomething= function () {
     $scope.check = true;
 }
```

I want to set css class to onclicked element only. Using this code I change on multiple elements. How to limit only to one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value of `check` variable as follow.
And in `ng-class` compare the value of `check` to the respective value.

```
<a ng-class="{'active' : check === 1}" ng-click="check = 1">1</a>
<a ng-class="{'active' : check === 2}" ng-click="check = 2">2</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/z82opSOoxh0cKrIezabn?p=preview)

With a function in controller:

```
<a ng-class="{'active' : check === 1}" ng-click="doSomething(1)">1</a>
<a ng-class="{'active' : check === 2}" ng-click="doSomething(2)">2</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.doSomething= function (index) {
    $scope.check = index;
};
```

Comment: You should use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: it works with your example but I have already wired up event on ng-click. How can I use with my concrete example, is it possible to use two ng-click parameters?

Comment: thanks, one more thing. how can I apply this css class on multiple elements using your approach?

Comment: Use the same condition on those elements